# Why do clicks within Popover.Panel close the panel when within Tab.Panel?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, headless-ui

I've been using [@headlessui/react](https://headlessui.dev/) for a project and it's helped me be very productive! But I've found an issue where one component interferes with another. I think I've found the general area of the issue and can provide a reproduction but I want to know:

1. Why specifically is this happening?
2. What solutions might fix this behavior either as a workaround or within the [headlessui/react](https://headlessui.dev/) library itself?

### The Issue

When using the `Popover` component within a `Tab.Panel` component, the `Popover.Panel` does not behave correctly. According to [the docs](https://headlessui.dev/react/popover):

> When the panel is open, clicking anywhere outside of its contents, pressing the Escape key, or tabbing away from it will close the Popover.

However, when the `Popover` is within a `Tab` component ([docs](https://headlessui.dev/react/tabs)) the behavior is inconsistent. For me, in Chrome, clicks within the `Popover.Panel` close the panel unless the click is on a `button` and in Safari the panel closes in all cases. Focusing the button with the keyboard allows selection though.

### Reproduction

I created a simplified version of the issue in [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/busy-sid-bnnioe?file=/src/App.js)

I think this has something to do with the `Tab` component capturing the `focus` from the `Popover.Panel` which in turn closes the `Popover.Panel`.

I added this snippet from ["Console logging the focused element as it changes"](https://hidde.blog/console-logging-the-focused-element-as-it-changes/) to the reproduction and the `Tab.Panel` seems to have the `focus` after clicking in `Popover.Panel`:

```
document.addEventListener(
  "focusin",
  function () {
    console.log("focused: ", document.activeElement);
  },
  true
);
```

Can anyone provide an explanation of what is happening and suggestions for simple remedies?

Answer (score 5):

I can now answer why specifically this is happening and also provide a possible solution.

I was able to simplify my case a bit. This will happen whenever `Popover` is inside a focusable element (which `Tab.Panel` is). I think it's [here](https://github.com/tailwindlabs/headlessui/blob/807ae66b8dc489214428f433eaf346851241e00d/packages/%40headlessui-react/src/components/popover/popover.tsx#L200-L226) in the PopoverRoot that whenever the activeElement is outside of the group the panel is closed.

If the `Popover` is inside an element with `tabindex="0"` then that element will be the `activeElement` and the panel will be closed. I updated the [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/busy-sid-bnnioe?file=/src/App.js) reproduction to demo this without using `Tab` and also propose a workaround but I'm not sure if it's an appropriate solution or not.

The workaround appears to be just adding `tabIndex="0"` to the `Popover.Panel` so that it is the `activeElement`. Is there a reason this shouldn't be done or could cause other unexpected behavior?

Comment: Thank you so much! I spent too much time trying to figure out how to solve it. In my case, the popover was inside a <a></a>, and it was impossible to remove it. The <a> was the issue; adding the tabindex="0" works like a charm.